# TypeError at /app/^detail/(?P1[0-9]+)/$ detail() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk'

Tags: python, html, django

I got an error,

```
TypeError at /app/^detail/(?P1[0-9]+)/$
detail() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk'
```

.
I wrote urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('top/', views.top, name='top'),
    path(r'^detail/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$',views.detail , name='detail'),
]
```

in views.py

```
def top(request):
    content = POST.objects.order_by('-created_at')
    page = _get_page(blog_content, request.GET.get('page'))
    return render(request, 'top.html',{'content':content,"page":page})

def detail(request):
    content = POST.objects.order_by('-created_at')
    return render(request, 'detail.html',{'content':content})
```

in top.html

```html
    <div>
             {% for content in page %}
                <div>
                     <h2>{{ content.title }}</h2>
                </div>
             {% endfor %}
     </div>
     <div>
             {% for content in page %}
                <h2>{{ content.title }}</h2>
                <p><a href="{% url 'detail' content.pk %}">SHOW DETAIL</a></p>
             {% endfor %}
     </div>
```

When I put "SHOW DETAIL" button, this error happens.I really cannot understand why I can't access pk. pk is default value, so I think I can access it from everywhere.I wanna make a system when I put "SHOW DETAIL button",content's detail is shown.What is wrong in my code?How should I fix this?Am I wrong to write url?Or is this error's meaning I should write pk in detail method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the new `path()` function, which does not take a regex. Either go back to the old `url()` function, or use `<type:name>` syntax:

```
path('detail/<int:pk>/', ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

In the view function `detail()`, there's no argument named `pk`. Add it as the second argument should solve your problem:

`def detail(request, pk):`